# Flutter custom slider that starts from middle

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a CustomSlider widget that is like an `X-axis`. So the default location of the thumb is `0`. The range is `-1` to `+1`. I need to show the active track of the slider. So if the thumb moves to the right I need to make the track from `0` to the current position of the thumb active. Similarly, if the thumb moves to the left the active track will be 0 to the thumb's position to the left.

Expected Output:

[image]

Code:

```
class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  double _value = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      width: widget.width,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                child: Container(
                  width: widget.width,
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.grey[800]!,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                right: _value > 0 ? (widget.width / 2 - _value * 200) : -(widget.width / 2 - _value * 200),
                left: _value > 0 ? widget.width / 2 : -(widget.width / 2),
                child: Container(
                  width: widget.width,
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 11.5,
                left: (widget.width / 2 - 10) * (_value + 1),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value += details.primaryDelta! / (widget.width / 2 - 10);
                      _value = _value.clamp(-1.0, 1.0);
                      widget.onChanged(_value);
                      if (_value == 0.0) {
                        HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: thumb(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget thumb() {
    return Container(
      width: 20.0,
      height: 20.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The active track on the right seems okay when I move the thumb to the right. But I can't figure out what to do when the thumb moves left from `0` (default value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like this:

```dart
class CustomSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomSlider({required this.width, required this.onChanged, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final double width;
  final void Function(double) onChanged;

  @override
  State<CustomSlider> createState() => _CustomSliderState();
}

class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  double _value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        height: 40,
        width: widget.width,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) => Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                left: 0,
                width: widget.width,
                child: Container(
                  width: widget.width,
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.grey[800]!,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                left: widget.width / 2,
                width: widget.width / 2 * (_value + 1) - widget.width / 2,
                child: Container(
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                right: widget.width / 2,
                width: widget.width / 2 - widget.width / 2 * (_value + 1),
                child: Container(
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 11.5,
                left: (widget.width / 2 - 10) * (_value + 1),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value += details.primaryDelta! / (widget.width / 2 - 10);
                      _value = _value.clamp(-1.0, 1.0);
                      widget.onChanged(_value);

                      if (_value == 0.0) {
                        HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: thumb(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget thumb() => Container(
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        decoration:
            const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.pink),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation which is more similar to the look and feel of the official material 3 Slider:

```dart
class CustomSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final double value;
  final double min;
  final double max;
  final double width;
  final void Function(double) onChanged;

  const CustomSlider({
    super.key,
    required this.value,
    required this.width,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.min = -1,
    this.max = 1,
  }) : assert(max >= 0 && min <= 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final rangeValues = max - min;
    final zeroPosition = width * (-min) / rangeValues;

    return SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      width: width,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            left: 0,
            width: width,
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              height: 4,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (value > 0)
            Positioned(
              top: 20,
              left: zeroPosition,
              width: (value / rangeValues) * width,
              child: Container(
                height: 4,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
            )
          else
            Positioned(
              top: 20,
              right: zeroPosition,
              width: (-value / rangeValues) * width,
              child: Container(
                height: 4,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
          Positioned(
            top: 11.5,
            left: (width - 20) *
                (value >= 0 ? (value - min) : (rangeValues - max + value)) /
                rangeValues,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                final newValue =
                    (value + rangeValues * details.primaryDelta! / (width - 10))
                        .clamp(min, max);
                onChanged(newValue);
                if (value == 0) {
                  HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```